# Devise_invitable, how to invite users to one hotel and not all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

In the context where a user.admin has_many hotels, is there a way to invite a user to 1 hotel only? (e.g. many-to-many relationship between user and hotel, with join UserHotel table).

More concretely, the first problem I am encountering is that I am not able to properly insert the hotel_id param in the users/invitations_controller.

- **Error message:**`Couldn't find Hotel without an ID. params sent: {"format"=>"109"}`

Please find my current code below=>

**views/hotels/show**

```
<%= link_to "invite new user", new_user_invitation_path(@hotel) %>
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    invitations: 'users/invitations'
  }

  resources :hotels do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

**models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hotels, through: :user_hotels
  enum role: [:owner, :admin, :employee]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :admin
  end

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :invitable
end

class UserHotel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_hotels

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['email'].blank? || attrs['role'].blank?}
end
```

**controllers/users/invitations**

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @user = User.new
    How to build the join table UserHotel when inviting?
  end
end
```

Comment: what is inside the `params` variable?

Answer (score 0):

add this code to `app/models/user.rb`:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_hotels
```

and then:

```
User.new(user_hotels_attributes: [{ hotel: @hotel }])
```

**you can add your own validations to prevent duplicate entry.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The params still remain ```params sent: {"format"=>"109"}``` This additional result of the code is  ```app/controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => ...rks_attributes: {[hotel: @hotel]} ) ... ^```

Comment: sorry, curly braces was in bad place

Comment: Thanks for the response, this bring me one step closer:) . With ```User.new(user_hotels_attributes:[{hotel:@hotel}])```, I indeed do not get an error message. Nevertheless, the hotel params are still not sent properly to the new action (e.g. ```{"format"=>"109"}``` instead of ```id=>109 ```)